# make sees different PATH than account's .bashrc-configured PATH

Tags: unix, path, makefile, environment-variables, shellcheck

I want to call [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), a Haskell program for linting shell scripts, from a `Makefile`.

When I install ShellCheck via `cabal install`, it is installed as `~/.cabal/bin/shellcheck`. So, I have configured Bash accordingly:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:~/.cabal/bin"

$ source ~/.bashrc
$ shellcheck -V
ShellCheck - shell script analysis tool
version: 0.3.4
license: GNU Affero General Public License, version 3
website: http://www.shellcheck.net
```

This enables me to run `shellcheck` from any directory in Bash. However, when I try to call it from a Makefile, `make` cannot find `shellcheck`.

```
$ cat Makefile
shlint:
    -shlint lib/

shellcheck:
    -shellcheck lib/**

lint: shlint shellcheck

$ make shellcheck
shellcheck lib/**
/bin/sh: 1: shellcheck: not found
make: [shellcheck] Error 127 (ignored)
```

I think that make is not receiving the same `PATH` as my normal Bash shell. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$HOME`, not `~`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin"
```

The `~`-means-home-directory feature is not supported in pathnames everywhere in all shells.  When `make` runs a recipe it doesn't use the user's shell (that would be a disaster!) it uses `/bin/sh` always.

On some systems (particularly Debian/Ubuntu-based GNU/Linux distributions) the default `/bin/sh` is not bash, but rather dash.  Dash doesn't support `~` being expanded in the `PATH` variable.

In general, you should reserve `~` for use on the command line as a shorthand.  But in scripting, etc. you should always prefer to write out `$HOME`.

*ETA:*

Also, the double-star syntax `lib/**` is a non-standard feature of shells like `bash` and `zsh` and will not do anything special in `make` recipes.  It is identical to writing `lib/*`.

You can force make to use a different shell than `/bin/sh` by adding:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

to your makefile, for example, but this makes it less portable (if that's an issue).

Comment: Thanks, MadScientist!